# Undefined result in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery

my code is some thing like this , and in success result msg.d is undefined . i think it is related to formdata as value that is passed to jquery ajax . but i dont know can i resolve it .what is wrong with that ?!

```
  var files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;   // i get it in drop event 
  var data = new FormData();

  jQuery.each(files, function (i, file) {
    data.append('file-' + i, file);
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: parameters.Url,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (msg) {        //my return value from webservice is just "hello"
      alert(msg.d);
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: I return just a string as a sucess value ,,, just "Hello"

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
      return "Hello World";
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your above comment can understand that,
You are actually returning just a string from your server side. And in your client side you are trying to alert an argument 'd' from the ajax return. This d is not at all present.

and when you alert message you are getting message [object XMLDocument]. this XML element can change to string if you specify 'dataType: "text",' in your ajax call.

So please try like this.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: parameters.Url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (msg) {       
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
```

Hope this will work fine for you.

Comment: i get this message "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>"   actually i get my webservice value as xml format ... and now how can i get it as a simple text ,just "Hello World" ?

Comment: If you just want text then return text from the server. Answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew . it`s so useful and helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
[WebMethod] 
public string HelloWorld() 
{ 
   xmlDoc.LoadXml("<root><item>Hello World</item></root>");
   return xmlDoc.OuterXML;
}
```

Comment: The data type in the ajax call should also change then. I think this is just an issue of "Human error type mismatch".

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to alert msg or msg.success?

What is your return value from the ajax page?

Make sure you have a return argument 'd' from your ajax page.

Comment: Yes ... alert(msg)  shows me "[object XMLDocument]" as a message ... and alert(msg.d)  shows me undefined ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 //my return value from webservice is just "hello"
```

If `msg` == "Hello"; then what should `msg.d` be? If you're only passing a string as a result, I don't see how that string can have a `.d` property attached to it.

Comment: By default WebMethod returns XML

Comment: By default. But in the poster's own comment: [WebMethod] public string HelloWorld() { return "Hello World"; }